# mp3 duplicate remover by listening & not tag based

Tags: windows, file-management, mp3, duplicate

I am reviewing a few mp3 duplicate remover which are not tag based but sound analysis based. These are the ones I found. [Similarity](http://www.music-similarity.com), [Audio Dedupe](http://www.mindgems.com/products/Duplicate-MP3-Finder/Audio-Dedupe-About.htm), [Audio Comparer](http://audiocomparer.com) & [Music Duplicate Remover](http://www.maniactools.com/soft/music-duplicate-remover/?ref=duplicates&version=6.0&b=6013). Any others? If you tried these which one is the best and why? Must be Windows based.

Comment: Don't expect too much of these programs, and verify very very well before deleting any "duplicates".

Comment: Some work pretty good although not perfect. I have thousands of files and don't have time to verify each. It's OK if some are deleted when they shouldn't.

Comment: any luck there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Music Duplicate Remover worked for me. I didn't like Similarity. It was too complicated.